# Java.sql.Date to Oracle database Date and Timestamp

Tags: sql, spring, date, jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC template for jdbc operations.
Since I am using BeanPropertySqlParameterSource, the bean's START_TIME variables is assigned with java.sql.date type.
in Oracle db, the column is mentioned as "DATE" type (and don't have TIMESTAMP type, even the db is 10.2 ver)

Now when I set

```
bean.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTime())
```

it's storing with date and time stamp as 00:00:00

Please tell me how can i Store the time stamp also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `java.sql.Timestamp`

```
 bean.setStartTime(new java.sql.Timestamp(...))
```

`java.sql.Date` removes the time part

[From the Javadocs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

> *To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.*

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date d=new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However adding some explanation may certainly help the OP.